# PHP - Append an arrays value to another array when the keys are not unique

Tags: php, arrays

I have a query that returns me these results

```
array (size=6)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[14]
      public 'ReplyTo' => int 18
      public 'ReplyFrom' => int 21
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[15]
      public 'ReplyTo' => int 19
      public 'ReplyFrom' => int 21
  2 => 
    object(stdClass)[16]
      public 'ReplyTo' => int 19
      public 'ReplyFrom' => int 22
  3 => 
    object(stdClass)[17]
      public 'ReplyTo' => int 20
      public 'ReplyFrom' => int 22
  4 => 
    object(stdClass)[18]
      public 'ReplyTo' => int 17
      public 'ReplyFrom' => int 22
  5 => 
    object(stdClass)[19]
      public 'ReplyTo' => int 18
      public 'ReplyFrom' => int 22
```

I need this kind of array to use the data:

```
array (size=2)
  ReplyFrom => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => ReplyTo
      1 => ReplyTo
  21 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 18
      1 => 19
```

I have tried this so far but it always overrides the value instead of adding it.

```
foreach($stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ) as $quote) {
    $test[$quote->ReplyFrom] = array($quote->ReplyTo);
}
```

My question is: How can I append the values with the same key to the array instead of overwriting it?

Comment: `$test[$quote->ReplyFrom][] = $quote->ReplyTo;`?

Comment: It will make this much easier if you give an example of the result you expect.

Comment: @u_mulder This brings me a step closer. I have 4 sub-arrays now for each value.

Comment: @Pharaoh The example that I aim to archive is the one under "I need this kind of array to use the data:"

Comment: What sub-arrays are you talking about?